# Pytest - how to access all collected test reports for reporting?

Tags: python, pytest, datadog

I am looking to gather all test reports from a pytest session and send them to DataDog as log messages.

As part of this process I want to be able to do a bulk creation and send of the analytics (vs sending on each test report).

From what I can tell, all reporting hooks run per test - https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#reporting-hooks

This means if I'm going to do this each test will incur a slight delay as the call to send results to DataDog will happen sequentially and once per test.

Ideally, I'd be able to iterate over and parse the entire test report for each test case in one hook and build a single API call to DataDog (or send multiple, in cases when there are too many results).

Is it possible with a pytest hook to have access to *all* test results in a single hook?

Comment: Would something like this work? https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/special.html

Another idea might be https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-harvest/

Comment: @JeffWright I ended up writing a pytest plugin to do it myself :)